# find number of records of different user in the table sql

Tags: sql

I have a table in which the data is as followed

```
sr     file     userName
1       12         1
2       12         1
3       12         1
4       13         5
5       14         5
```

now I want to get the data like the following

```
userName   TotalRecords
1              3
5              2
```

what can I do to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Hint: `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the user name and count the records (it doesnt matter what you count btw):

```
SELECT Count(sr), userName From YourTableName GROUP BY userName
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple [count aggregation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_count.asp) is what you need.

```
SELECT userName,
       COUNT(userName)
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY userName
```

Answer (score 0):

use `count()` function with group by userName

```
select userName, count(*) as TotalRecords from t
group by userName
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping and count() would solve the problem

```
SELECT col1,COUNT(col2) FROM tableName GROUP BY col1
```